# how to make div scrollable only horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want this tab list horizontally scrollable when there are more tab items. Right now it is getting wrapped and comes in next line.

```
    link1
    link2
    link3



     
        some content
     

        some content
     

        some content
```

Comment: here the link1,link2,link3 are tab items and they have their respective tab content.

Comment: Please share the relevant portions of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve thi simply by using.

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.content {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    link1
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    link2
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    link3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AnkitaAdhikari you are welcome. Please approve my answer if that works for you. Happy to have an upvote aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-x`:

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: /*chosen width*/;
}
```